# Why are member variables visible in c++ constructor initialization lists?

Tags: c++, initializer-list

I came across this due to a bug in my code and I'm curious why it's allowed. What reason is there that allows object members to be visible in the constructor initialization list?

```
#include <stdio.h>

class derived {
  private:
    int * value2;
  public:
    derived();
};

derived::derived()
 : value2(value2){} // Uninitialized self-assignment

int main()
{
  derived thisChild;
}
```

Clang gives a warning about this but unfortunately g++ does not.

Comment: G++ _does_ warn if you use 4.7 and `-Winit-self`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you can initalise one member using another; this is perfectly fine if the other has already been initialised, or if you're just using its address to initialise a pointer or reference. For example:

```
struct Thingy
{
    int & r;
    int a;
    int b;

    Thingy(int x) :
        r(a),   // OK - a has a valid address, and we're not using the value
        a(x),
        b(a)    // OK - a has been initialised
    {}
};
```

It would be rather tricky to allow that and disallow your example.

Answer (score 2):

If it is not visible, you cannot write this:

```
A(int n) : some_num(n), another_num(some_num*10) {}
```

then what would be the point of member-initialization list?

As for self-initialization (uninitialized variable), you can do even this:

```
int xyz = xyz; //will compile
```

Comment: The question is about initializing a member with a member, not a member with a parameter.

Comment: @MarkRansom, read the answer again. The second initialisier in the example from Nawaz uses the value of first initialised data member and the OP explicitly asks why members are visible in the initialisation list.

Comment: @HristoIliev, the answer was modified since I left my comment. Originally the constructor example was simply `A(int n) : some_num(n) {}`.

Comment: @HristoIliev: Mark is right. While I was adding more stuff to my answer, he had posted the comment. So initially `another_num(some_num*10)` part was not there, and I was adding this part.

Comment: Race condition acknowledged :)

Answer (score 0):

You can think of the initialization list as part of the body of the method (specifically the constructor), so it is natural that you can access the member variables of an object in one of its methods

Also, you might want to reuse an already created member variable to initialize others -- *note*: you will have to know the exact order of initialization (order of member variable declaration) to make sure you are using this portably

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean why are member variables accessible in initializer expressions.

One reason is that the initialization of one member variable can depend on another.

That's fragile, but sometimes necessary to avoid awkward code such as artificial base classes.